# Custom source set in Gradle imported to IntelliJ 14

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I'm trying to get Gradle (2.1) and IntelliJ (14.0.2) to play nicely. Specifically, I have imported a sample Gradle project containing a separate source set for integration tests into IntelliJ.

The project builds fine using Gradle on the command line, and I'm able to run the integration tests successfully. When running inside IntelliJ on the other hand, I have two problems:

1) Compiling inside IntelliJ fails, due to a dependency in the integration test to a third-party library (commons-collections) which fails to resolve.

2) If I remove the dependency above and compile, I'm not able to run the integration test inside IntelliJ. I get the following error message:

> No tests found for given includes: [org.gradle.PersonIntegrationTest.canConstructAPersonWithAName]

The file structure looks like this:

```
src
  integration-test
    java
    resources
  main
    java
    resources
  test
    java
    resources
build.gradle
```

And build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    integrationTestCompile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2'
    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integrationTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integrationTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integrationTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: jar) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    systemProperties['jar.path'] = jar.archivePath
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

Any ideas on how to make this work would be much appreciated.

The full Gradle sample project is available in the Gradle distribution, under samples/java/withIntegrationTests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell IDEA to map entries from your `integrationTest` configuration into your project as TEST dependencies. I am not sure whether you need to add source root directories too. The important part is:

```groovy
idea {
  module {
    //and some extra test source dirs
    testSourceDirs += file('some-extra-test-dir')
    generatedSourceDirs += file('some-extra-source-folder')
    scopes.TEST.plus += [ configurations.integrationTest ]
  }
}
```

More is described in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

---

Edits to reflect Daniel's comments: `generatedSourceDirs` is is Gradle 2.2+. 
To set up the test task you will use task like

```groovy
task integTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("${project.testResultsDir}/$name")
    reports.html.destination = file("${project.reporting.baseDir}/$name")
    shouldRunAfter test
}
check.dependsOn integTest
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work. I get the following error: Could not find property 'generatedSourceDirs' on org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule_Decorated. Also, would I need to add a integrationTest configuration in order for this to work.

Comment: The last sentence in my previous comment was supposed to end with a question mark, i.e. Also, would I need to add an 'integrationTest' configuration in order for this to work?